# Kubuntu 17.10 screen freeze during boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, freeze

After installing kubuntu and updating the suggested stuff on the first start it asks for a reboot. After the reboot it asks to set the credentials, timezone etc. again. So I do that, it gets set up and reboots again. On the following boot is where it freezes. It seems to do ok at first and gets to the stage with the pulsating kubuntu logo, then i get a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left corner. After a couple seconds it freezes and stays this way not reacting to any keyboard buttons pressed until i press the power button. Then it briefly shows the kubuntu logo again and turns off.

Answer (score 0):

exactly the same thing happens to me.

When you are in the black screen press ctrl+alt+f4

Type your user and enter.

Type your password and enter.

Type startx and enter.

I know it's not a solution but for now it allows me to use my computer.